# PHP script working locally but not when placed on webserver

Tags: php, parsing, localhost, screen-scraping

The following codes scrapes a list of links from a given webpage and then place them into another script that scrapes the text from the given links and places the data into a csv document. The code runs perfectly on localhost (wampserver 5.5 php) but fails horribly when placed on domain.

You can check out the functionality of the script at http://miskai.tk/ANOFM/csv.php .
Also, file get html and curl are both enabled onto the server.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Mehedinti.csv"');
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

include_once 'csv.php';
$urls = scrape_main_page();

function scraping($url) {
    // create HTML DOM

    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // get article block
    if ($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)) {

        foreach ($html->find('/html/body/table') as $article) {
            // get title

            $item['titlu'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[1]/td/div', 0)->plaintext);

            // get body
            $item['tr2'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr3'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr4'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr5'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr6'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr7'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr8'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr9'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr10'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr11'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
            $item['tr12'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[12]/td/div/]', 0)->plaintext);
            $ret[] = $item;
        }

        // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);

        return $ret;}
}



$output = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach ($urls as $url) {

    $ret = scraping($url);

    foreach($ret as $v){
        fputcsv($output, $v);}

}

fclose($output);
exit();
```

second file

```
<?php

function get_contents($url) {
    // We could just use file_get_contents but using curl makes it more future-proof (setting a timeout for example)
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,));

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}

function scrape_main_page() {
    set_time_limit(300);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Prevent DOMDocument from spraying errors onto the page and hide those errors internally ;)
    $html = get_contents("http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/index2.jsp?judet=26");

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    die(var_dump($html));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $xpath->query("//table[@width=\"645\"]/tr");

    $all = array();
    //var_dump($results);
    for($i = 1; $i < $results->length; $i++) {
        $tr = $results->item($i);

        $id = $tr->childNodes->item(0)->textContent;
        $requesturl = "http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=" . urlencode($id) .
            "&judet=26";
        $details = scrape_detail_page($requesturl);

        $newObj = new stdClass();
        $newObj = $id;
        $all[] = $newObj;
    }

    foreach($all as $xtr) {
        $urls[] = "http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=" . $xtr .
            "&judet=26";
    }
    return $urls;
}


scrape_main_page();
```

Comment: those who can do, those who can't crape other peoples sites.

Comment: What do your webserver error logs say?

Comment: Curl error: Failed connect to lmvz.anofm.ro:8080; Connection timed outbool(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the problem here is your php.ini configuration. Make sure the server supports curl and fopen. If not start your own linux server.